# can I make Mac OS Bootcamp boot to most recently used OS

Tags: mac, boot-camp

I use Bootcamp on a MacBook Pro to run Windows7.
I also mostly use an external screen and keyboard, and keep the laptop lid closed during normal operation.

When Win7 demands to reboot following an update or software installation, I have to frantically open up the laptop in order to hit the 'option' key to trigger Bootcamp before the time limit expires.

The sensible thing would be for Bootcamp to boot into the most recently used OS by default, but I haven't been able to find a way to configure this.

Is it possible? Any idea how ?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/), which is a boot menu and maintenance toolkit for EFI. You can set it to have a small timeout so upon restart you get the Choose OS menu without having to hold down the option key.

Comment: +1 Yes, refit is your best bet and you should use it regardless of the question here.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're in Windows more than you're in OS X. What's wrong with setting the startup disk to default to Windows so that it'll boot there without your interaction?